# Проблемы с высотой в Mozilla Firefox

Tags: padding, html, firefox, css

Есть код:

```
<div style="background: red; padding: 2px">test</div>
```

Почему-то Mozilla Firefox делает блок по высоте больше, чем другие браузеры. То есть в данном браузере получается размер `3px`, хотя прописано `2px`;

Как решить проблему? Задавать `height` **не предлагать**!

Comment: А без padding: 2px размеры вашего блока совпадают во всех браузерах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете в крайнем случае через префикс -moz- персонально для нее задать (подобрать) такой отступ, чтоб размер стал, как в остальных браузерах.

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать задать font-size и line-height, обычно после этого во всех браузерах одинаково все выглядит

Comment: Ничего не помогло.

Comment: А можно посмотреть как оно выглядит? Наживом примере все-таки легче понять, что может быть не так